# Outlook rules for Compound Distribution lists

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules, distribution-list

I have a rule setup in place to move emails to a specific folder when they are sent to one Distribution List I'm part of, lets call it **@Managers**. This was working fine until someone decided to include that list as part of other distribution lists, for instance **@Helpdesk**. So now all emails sent to **@Helpdesk** are also being moved to my folder. This is highly disruptive because as you can imagine the volume on emails sent to **@Helpdesk** is obscenely high. I'm just interested in emails sent explicitly to **@Managers**.

Is there a way to distinguish between an email sent to **@Helpdesk** and one sent to just **@Managers** or how can I filter that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Rules to process HelpDesk first, Managers second.